# Determine the type of the submanifold: Immersed/Embedded. Simple example.

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, solution-verification

I want to clarify the notion of a closed submanifold. We say that $X$ is a closed submanifold of a smooth $n$-dim manifold $M$ if there is a closed embedding of $X$ onto $M$ i.e. a smooth map $f:X\to M$ where $f$ is a proper injective immersion. So, is there a notion of an open submanifold? Is the following example an open submanifold?

**Example:** Consider an open interval $I=(0,1)$ and the map $f:I\to\mathbb{R}^2$ given by $f(t)=(t,0)$. We can see that $f$ is an immersion since $df_a$ is injective for all $a\in I$ as $df_a=
\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$.

However, $f$ is not proper since the preimage of the unit square $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, compact set, is an open interval $(0,1)$ which is not compact. But, we can see that we can consider that $f(I)$ is open in the subspace topology of $f(I)$ since we can find an open ball $B$ centered at $(1/2,0)$ with a radius $r=1/2$ whose intersection with $f(I)$ is exactly $f(I)$.

*Question:* So, do we consider $f(I)$ to be an open submanifold?

Comment: Your definition of closed embedding is strange. It should be something more to the effect of, "topological embedding with closed image". A closed submanifold is then an immersion that is also a closed embedding. Similarly, an open submanifold is an immersion that is an open embedding (= topological embedding with open image). It just so happens that closed embeddings are proper maps – but this is not true of open embeddings. Your example is neither open nor closed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Oh, I use the definition given in Cannas da Silva book which says that f is a closed embedding if f is a proper injective immersion. Then we can show that it is equivalent to say that f is an embedding, i.e. homeomorphic to its image, and the image of f is closed in M.

Comment: So, I have two more questions. 1) Does it follows that the dimension of any open submanifold of M is equal to the dimension of M? 2) In my example, is f(I) considered to be a submanifold of M? If yes, then do we just say that it is neither open nor closed?